# ::before and ::After pseudo elements used with pseudo classes with several <p> elements selectors

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

In this example, as you can see, " p:first-child::before " does not work. Is there a way to have two p elements without using .classes? I would like to only use before and after pseudo elements with first-child, last-child or nth-child so I can have a content added before the first p element and have a content added after the second

element.  Here is the code I'm using and the outcome I would like.

I can't get the ::before pseudo element to show the "Hi, " content at the same time that the ::after is being used on the second p element.  Am I doing it wrong or it's just not possible with those pseudo element and class elements together?
Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p:first-child::before {
            content: "Hi, ";
        }

        p:last-child::after {
            content: " and I like it";
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Demo of the ::before selector</h1>

        <p>My name is Donald</p>
        <p>I live in Ducksburg</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

The outcome I would like is this:

Hi, My name is Donald
I live in Duckburg and I like it

The outcome I get is this:

My name is Donald
I live in Duckburg and I like it

Comment: Use :first-of-type